# create REST webservices in Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, web-services, rest, symfony

I am planning to create application which has a database built into MySQL and to access those data `i am planning to create REST webservices which returns the data in JSON , so that it can be easily access from JQuery Client.`

Moreover , i have installed Symfony 2.0 successfully , `as i am new to this framework` , i don't know how can i create REST webservices from database.

so can anyone suggest me or give me a road map to kick start with a development of Rest Webservices in symfony.

***If any one has some batter solution to create webservice in PHP then please suggest***

Comment: Do you really need the full stack Symfony 2.0 for this project? Maybe you can have a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) which it builds ont top of Symfony 2 Components. It's really fast to built an api with it !

Comment: I really don't know whether it will be required or not as i am new to it

Answer (score 2):

FOSRestBundle is a good place to start - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle

Comment: Depends on what you want. Symfony2 is a full fledged stack with authorization/authentication, ORM, templating, etc. If you do not need all that, then silex is a lightweight alternative. And scalability is something only you can determine depending on your setup.

Comment: Go ahead with FOSRestBundle, you will not regret

Answer (score 0):

In addition to prepare the RESTfull API via FOSRestBundle you can use Symfony Forms to validate and process the input data